# Putting MD5 user/pass on client window, Is my method secure?

Tags: php, md5

I am making a save feature for my paint editing app. Here is the pseudo code behind it.

```
<?php

$user=md5(POST["user"]);
$pass=md5(POST["pass"]); // Get user/pass from the login.php (or this page when saving).

if POST["save"]{

    check_database_whether_credentials_match() or die();

    save_photo();
    exit();
}

include("login") or die(); //log in with data
?>

<button> Save Photo </button>


function userpressesButton(){

    ajax(post:{"save":getImage(),"user":<? echo $user ?>, "pass": <? echo $pass ?>})
// MD5 username and passwords will be here
}
```

When the user presses the button, it will activate `userpressesButton`, which sends the post data (including user,pass and drawing) to the same page where it will be seen by the PHP code on the top of the snippet.

Is putting MD5 username and passwords into the clients webpage,.. safe? It is encrypted so I'm guessing it seems safe to put it there.

Comment: why are you using md5 on the user name? why are you using md5 at all? where's the salt ...

Comment: MD5 is not safe at all, it's super quick to turn any string into an MD5, so it's only one more step for a brute-force attack to take, and it won't increase the crack time very much...

Comment: If the user is authenticated, then just use sessions.  There's no reason to have any of that information in the client side source.

Comment: Hmm, I never heard of sessions,, Ill have to take a look!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have no idea why you would render the password (md5 or otherwise) on the page displayed to the user
2. Don't use md5 to store the password on the server, use [bcyrpt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Comment: It is so I can compare it to the database password when I make an ajax call to the same page.

Comment: Your login mechanism is flawed.. if you need to verify the password with every request the design is inherently insecure. with this design it would be trivial for any user to impersonate any other user.

Comment: Huh, How can a user impersonate another user? They need the log in credentials.

Comment: simply stated login systems are hard, every body makes the same mistakes trying to roll their own. you should use something that been tested and used by lots of people like http://php-login.net/

Comment: Wow, cool, Ill check it out!

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer acceptable to use MD5 to secure anything, because it isn't secure. It's quite trivial to take an MD5 hash and brute force it.

You need to generate a salt and then encrypt the password with something like [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) or [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

So to answer your question, no it's not secure. It might be secure from someone standing their looking at the screen, but that's about it.